# FBX import of physics simulation model

Tags: animation, import, .fbx

I have exported a physics simulation model (wind turbine) as FBX from a simulation program where every rigid body has animated location, rotation, and scaling properties. There is no skeleton defined.
When checking the exported model with FBX Review everything is displayed fine.
Translation, rotation, and scaling are applied in the correct order.
But importing this model into blender I can see that only the first specified
property animation (translation) is applied but all others are ignored. If I
change the order of the animations to first scale, then rotate, then translate,
only the scaling occurs.

Is that expected and I need some further action on the Blender side, or am I
missing something obvious? Thanks for any help on this issue.

Using Blender 3.3.1 on Windows 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue. When exporting I had placed translation, rotation and scaling on separate animation layers. Blender only imports the first animation layer. Adding them to a single animation layer works like a charm.